# What are some interesting topics for a differential geometry essay?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

As an assignment I have been asked to write an essay on an aspect related to differential geometry. My lecturer has proposed topics such as architecture, navigation and computer graphics. I personally find these boring. I would like to talk about something interesting in relation to physics and the universe. Could anyone provide some particularly interesting suggestions? The reason I am posting this question is because I believe there is someone who knows something great that I could write about! These are the concepts that have been taught:

- Conic sections
- Special Parametric Curves (Cycloid etc)
- Arc length
- Curvature
- Osculating circles
- Evolutes
- Envelopes
- Total curvature
- Parametric curves
- Parametric surfaces
- Serret-Frenet Equations
- Osculating planes
- Area of surfaces in 3D
- Shape operator
- First fundamental form
- Second fundamental form
- Gaussian, mean, and principal curvature
- Umbilical points
- Minimal surfaces
- Geodesics and geodesic curvature
- Theorema Egregium
- Gauss-Bonnet Theorem

I will tick the answer that I find most interesting. Links are not necessary but are appreciated.

Thank you in advanced for your help!

Comment: Relating differential geometry to physics and the universe?  Sounds like General Relativity and Einstein's Field Equations are exactly the topics you're looking for.

Comment: [Applications of Differential Geometry to Physics
](http://www.aei.mpg.de/~gielen/diffgeo.pdf)

Comment: If you'd like more relevant people to look at this, attaching the (soft-question) tag will probably help. (I forgot to do this during my edit.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While other people will recommend relativity, let's take the road less travelled by: **bubbles**.

If you are looking for [particularly interesting physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69124/what-is-the-physics-behind-a-soap-bubble), then soap bubbles are the way to go. Not only do they relate to [minimal surfaces and mean curvature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_surface), but they're out-of-the-box. Plus, who *doesn't* want to have an excuse to write the word "bubble" all over a math essay?

Comment: Thank you! I found this particularly interesting and it opened some other great topics!